# How come my Angular1.6 bindings are not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn the new components and I have a weak understanding of bindings and the symbols.

How come I cannot get my ng-repeat to work with this code.. I have tried using controllerAs syntax, scope, changing the bindings, everything!

**APP.JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

/* Mock-Data */
app.constant('friends', [{
  firstName: 'Conner',
  lastName: 'A',
  location: 'Melborne, Australia'
}, {
  firstName: 'Dom',
  lastName: 'M',
  location: 'Los Angeles, CA'
}, {
  firstName: 'Bryan',
  lastName: 'A',
  location: 'Seattle, WA'
}, {
  firstName: 'Dan',
  lastName: 'M',
  location: 'Kalispell, MO'
}]);

app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['friends', function(friends) {
  this.$onInit = function() {
    console.log("HomeCtrl has been initialized");
    this.friends = friends;
    console.log(this.friends);
  };
}]);

app.component('myGrid', {
  templateUrl: 'grid.html',
  controller: 'HomeCtrl',
  bindings: {
    data: '<' // I have tried: &,<,=,@
  }
});
```

**Index.html**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
      <title>My AngularJS App</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">

      <my-grid data="friends"></my-grid>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

  </body>

  </html>
```

**Grid.html**

```
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Angular 1.X - Example Component</div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in data">
          <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.location }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

No matter what I try, I cannot get ng-repeat to work..

Comment: From where are you passing friends into you grid directive? Their should be some parent controller , in where you can inject you service and attach data to scope to pass it to the directive

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a controller scoped in index.html in order to tell angular where `friends` comes from. Can add an `ng-controller`to solve this

In component you are using `controllerAs` which is set to `vm` alias so you need to reference that in the view also

index.html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="HomeCtrl as ctrl">
      <my-grid data="ctrl.friends"></my-grid>
</div>
```

grid.html

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in vm.data">
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/PVQkW1yv0iRmU4vGQlQM?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: But then what is the point of declaring the controller in the component? From what I understand, this causes the controller to be instantiated twice?

Comment: You need an outer controller so you can even pass that data into the component

Comment: Would you be able to show me an article or something that will help me understand this? I do not get why. I thought by binding the controller to the component, the component has the information from the data="scope variable"

Comment: look at this version that now has 2 controllers (one for component and one for page) http://plnkr.co/edit/PVQkW1yv0iRmU4vGQlQM?p=preview

Comment: Ok that clears it up somewhat. So what is the point of even specifying a controller inside a component if it does not provide the data?

Comment: so you can have event functions, service injections etc. Controllers are not just for data

Comment: Ok.. So data can never be pulled from the component controller and injected into the component?

Comment: Sure it can but you wouldn't use bindings unless you were binding to a parent passing that in through the attributes

Comment: Is there anyway you could modify the example to show me how? I swear that is the last thing.. Thank you so much for your help. I guess I do not totally understand bindings then

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/YIQiJuA4fNavBFUGTFDy?p=preview No bindings, no ng-controller and uses `vm.friends` in view

Comment: AH! It finally clicked! So with using this, I am required to use controllerAs syntax. But when its scope, it doesnt matter since angular is smart enough to determine that  comes from the controller' scope. Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: case 1 using bindings binds to attributes and the attributes get data from parent ... case 2 controller already has the data and no need for bindings since component is self contained with all that it needs

Comment: Thank you that helped as well. So I was trying to tell angular to capture data from the binding by providing the attribute versus nesting the data in the template.

Answer (score 0):

> Your design is bit incorrect.You have not passed **friends** data to your directive from the parent scope.
>   [Working Plunk inline with you e.g](https://plnkr.co/edit/xr1tQn7JILxCk4RPEkqX?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("myApp",[])
.controller('ctr1', function($scope, friends){
     $scope.friends=friends;
})
.constant('friends', [{
  firstName: 'Conner',
  lastName: 'A',
  location: 'Melborne, Australia'
}, {
  firstName: 'Dom',
  lastName: 'M',
  location: 'Los Angeles, CA'
}, {
  firstName: 'Bryan',
  lastName: 'A',
  location: 'Seattle, WA'
}, {
  firstName: 'Dan',
  lastName: 'M',
  location: 'Kalispell, MOO'
}])

.component('myGrid', {
  templateUrl: 'grid.html',
  bindings: {
    friends: '<'
  },
  controller:function() {
          this.$onInit = function() {
            console.log(this.friends);
          }
  }
  
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.6" data-semver="1.5.6" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctr1">
  <div class="container">
    <my-grid friends="friends"></my-grid>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<!--************************Grid.html****************
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">Angular 1.X - Example Component</div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th>
          <th>Last Name</th>
          <th>Location</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in $ctrl.friends">
          <td>{{ employee.firstName }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.lastName }}</td>
          <td>{{ employee.location }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```